# How to check an "Either" result in Scala Test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am relatively new to Scala Test, and so I consulted the [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_EitherValues) on how to test on `Either` values.

I tried to replicate the instructions like that:

```
import org.scalatest.EitherValues
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

class EitherTest extends AnyFlatSpec with EitherValues {
  val either: Either[Exception, Int] = Right(42)

  either.right.value should be > 1
}
```

This implementation does not do the trick, I get a syntax error. What did I do wrong?

Error:

> Error:(9, 22) value should is not a member of Int either.right.value should be > 1 Error:(9, 29) not found: value be either.right.value should be > 1 – Hannes 14 hours ago

Comment: what is the error you get? can you add that as well please

Comment: `Error:(9, 22) value should is not a member of Int
  either.right.value should be > 1
Error:(9, 29) not found: value be
  either.right.value should be > 1`

Comment: Can you try removing the explicit type signature from Either and see if that works? ```val either = Right(42) ```

Comment: @Hannes: I think you're missing the mix-in `Matchers` (eg `class EitherTest extends AnyFlatSpec with EitherValues with Matchers`).

Comment: @Marth mixing-in `org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers` got rid of the syntax error but my IDE still states that `Either.right` is deprecated since Scala 2.13.0, Is that expected?

Comment: Yes Either.right is deprecated as it is right oriented.  either.contains or either.exists should work for you.

Comment: A workaround I found is using `with OptionValues` instead and then `either.toOption.value`.

Answer (score 6):

Testing Either by matching with pattern can be more readable.
ScalaTest's `Inside` trait allows you to make assertions after a pattern match.

```
import org.scalatest.Inside
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class EitherTest extends AnyFlatSpec with Inside with Matchers {
  val either: Either[Exception, Int] = Right(42)

  either should matchPattern { case Right(42) => }

  inside(either) { case Right(n) =>
    n should be > 1
  }

  val either2: Either[Exception, Int] = Left(new Exception("Bad argument"))

  inside(either2) { case Left(e) =>
    e.getMessage should startWith ("Bad")
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, I will give it a try! But I've got two questions: 1) What is that `=> }` syntax? I know the match syntax but I did not know that you can leave out the right part of the expression. 2) Can `matchPattern` be used together with the `"Either" should matchPattern in { ...}` syntax?

Comment: @Hannes 1. right part is empty Unit without any implementation. We have only checking either matched with the pattern.
2. More details about matching a pattern in Scalatest docs
http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#matchingAPattern

Answer (score 5):

There is an open pull request [Add EitherValuable #1712](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/pull/1712) which aims to address the fact that in Scala 2.13 the `RightProjection` is [deprecated](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/pull/975#issuecomment-538652491):

> at present `.right` is deprecated (and I believe it will stay that way)
>   but `.left` isn't, as per [scala/scala#8012](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8012)

The new syntax of `EitherValues` in future ScalaTest versions might become `rightValue` and `leftValue` like so

```
either.rightValue should be > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it.

Check first if it is right and then compare the value:

```
either.isRight shouldBe true
either.getOrElse(0) shouldBe 42
```

Another way is to fail in case it is not right:

```
either.getOrElse(fail("either was not Right!")) shouldBe 42
```

I also would wrap your test, for example as *WordSpec*:

```
"My Either" should {
  "be Right" in {
    either.getOrElse(fail("either was not Right!")) shouldBe 42
  }
}
```

This hints you where the problem is. Otherwise, if it fails, all you get is a nasty error stack.

And here the whole example:

```
class EitherTest
  extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with EitherValues {

  // val either: Either[Exception, Int] = Right(42)
  val either: Either[Exception, Int] = Left(new IllegalArgumentException)
  "My Either" should {
    "be Right" in {
      either.getOrElse(fail("either was not Right!")) shouldBe 42
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `shouldBe` appears not to exist. Is there another mix-in I need?

Comment: I think you missed the `with Matchers` see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the [inside](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_inside) trait? That way you can test for the value inside your Either using pattern matching. For example:

```
import org.scalatest.Inside.inside
...
val result = FooBarInputValidator(value)
inside(result) { case Left(validationError) => 
   validationError.message shouldBe "Invalid input"
   validationError.parameter shouldBe "FooBar"
}
```